# How can I update a column in a table based on the result set of a different table?

Tags: sql, t-sql

This is along the lines of what I want to do:

```
UPDATE [table1]
SET FirstName IN (SELECT [FirstName] FROM [table2])
```

There are 300 names that I need to update on [table1] with and the names are in [table2]. The names are NULLS. They need to be names from [table2].

The record set CAN be random. So no relationship needed between the tables.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: How are the tables related to each other? Do you have a foreign-key or is there a common column `name`?

Comment: No relation whatsoever. I basically generated the names in [table2] and I need to populate them in [table1]. Is there a way I can copy and paste the data into the new table? I remember with SQL management studio 2005 you were able to do this but not with 2008? unless I'm unaware.

Comment: Then you don't need to update table1. You want to insert all values from table2.

Comment: im not inserting new values though. i need to update the records that are already there. the first and last names of [table1] are null. they need to be updated with the list of names from [table2]

Comment: If the two tables have no relations, how do you know which record in table1 gets a name from table2?

Comment: @Testifier - Unless you have a mechanism to tell the RDBMS which name from table2 should be applied to which record in table1, then it is impossible with a query. You can't rely on the order in the table, because data stored in a table has no explicit order. You *must* have values (or be able to create values) that allow something similar to `Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON table1.id = table2.id`. If you think there may be a trick that we could employ, I'd advise you to give the *full* table definitions for both tables, as well as sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Neglecting the missing relationships, issues with ordering, or anything that might cause the data to be inaccurate**, you could try this, which will **arbitrarily** assign a row number to each record in the two tables, and match the two tables together with that number, and then update the Name field based on that match:

```
WITH Source AS 
(
    SELECT 
        Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RowNum
    FROM 
        [Table2]
), 
Destination AS 
(
    SELECT 
        Name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RowNum
    FROM 
        [Table1] 
)
UPDATE 
    d
SET 
    d.Name = s.Name
FROM 
    Source s
JOIN 
    Destination d 
    ON 
    s.RowNum = d.RowNum
```

**But:** without having something concrete that relates one table to the other, you could end up with the 300 names from the source table copied to a randomized set of 300 rows in your destination table.

---

**EDIT:** Based on your comment of wanting randomized data, if you change the `ROW_NUMBER()` columns to:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NEWID()))
```

you will truly get some randomized data.

Comment: Cory, this is exactly what I want. The names CAN be randomized. I'm going to give this a try now.

Comment: @Testifier: the word _random_ or _arbitrary_ would have helped us  a lot to understand your requirement.

Comment: @Testifier: Glad it worked. You will find that the more details you provide in your questions, the more accurate and complete (and fast!) your answers will be. For database or SQL-related questions, we really like schemas and sample data :)

Answer (score 2):

> There are 300 names that I need to populate [table1] with and the
>   names are in [table2].

Populate means insert, then this works:

```
INSERT INTO table1
    SELECT FirstName FROM table2;
```

Here's an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d2f4/1/0

Answer (score 1):

If you simply trying to create NEW records in Table one, then do the following:

```
insert into Table1 (FirstName)
select FirstName from Table2
```

If you need to update the records, you do the following:

```
update t1
   set FirstName = t2.FirstName,
       LastName  = t2.LastName
  from Table1 t1
  join Table2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID   -- (or whatever key you are using to join the two tables)
```

Comment: as i mentioned above, im not creating new records. im updating existing ones.